# php PG_fetch_array/assoc returns false

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, join

I am converting my code from Mysql to PostgreSql and I encountered problem while doing fetch query. Could you please explain me why it returns false for each row ?

```
if($_GET['type']==2){
$return=array();
$first=1;
    $limit= pg_fetch_assoc(pg_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student"));
    while($first<=$limit['count']){
         //array_push($return, pg_fetch_assoc(pg_query($connection, "SELECT st.id as id,
         $fetcher= pg_fetch_assoc(pg_query($connection, "SELECT st.id as id,
                                (round(avg(m.score),1)+round(avg(s.score),1)+round(avg(dm.score),1)+round(avg(e.score),1)+round(avg(pr.score),1)) as total_score,
                                            st.name as name,
                                            st.surname as surname,
                                            st.class as class,
                                            2 as info_type,
                                            st.missed_lessons as missed_lessons,
                                            round(avg(m.score),1) as avgm,
                                            round(avg(s.score),1) as avgs,
                                            round(avg(dm.score),1) as avgdm,
                                            round(avg(e.score),1) as avge,
                                            round(avg(pr.score),1) as avgpr
                                                 FROM student st
                                         RIGHT JOIN math m ON st.id=m.student_id
                                         RIGHT JOIN sport s ON st.id=s.student_id
                                         RIGHT JOIN database_managment dm ON st.id=dm.student_id
                                         RIGHT JOIN english e ON st.id=e.student_id
                                         RIGHT JOIN programming pr ON st.id=pr.student_id WHERE st.id=".$first." GROUP BY st.id"));
        $first++;
        echo json_encode($fetcher);
     }
    //echo json_encode($return);
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the query?

Comment: Right joins... Most people have problems enough with left join... (If you want to write code that can be read, understood and maintained by others, switch to left join instead.)

Comment: @jarlh Left Joins didn't change anytghing

Comment: @Mureinik Output I get is 1 false
2 false
3 false .. 50 false And I have set error reporting on.

Comment: @user3801263, I didn't say you'd get another result. It was a just a tip on how to write maintainable code!

Comment: @jarlh Yes, yes, I usually use LJ, but I need to gather avg scores, Well all this worked on MySql just fine !